# How can I prevent the same-origin-access-policy with MVC4 and WebAPI projects?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have asked similar questions before but I have finally come to the root of my problem. I have a solution in VS 2010 with two projects. One project is an mvc 4 application that makes a rest call to the second WebAPI project, now even though these projects are in the same solution I get a same-origin policy error when using anything other than I.E. I believe this has to do with the fact that each project gets launched on a separate dev server instance but I am  not sure.

Can someone please explain a solution to me where I can have both of these projects running without encountering the same origin error? (Related side question, if I ever wanted to expose my api to public use how would anyone use it without getting the same error?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing and what worked for me, for now is using IIS Express and pointing the projects to the same virtual directory

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a thin proxy layer within your main MVC4 application that makes `HttpRequest` or `WebClient` calls to your WebAPI project.

So your Javascript will call something like

```
http://samedomain/proxy/getproduct/29
```

Your ProxyController's GetProduct action should then make an HttpRequest call to the actual WebAPI URL

```
http://otherdomain/api/Product/29
```

And return that `JsonResult` back to the calling Javascript where you can then work with it.  Because your Javascript and proxy layer are in the same domain, you won't face the origin access policy issue.

Edit: Even if you have both of them on localhost but with different ports, that counts as a separate domain as far as the browser is concerned.  A call from localhost:41928 to localhost:58128 will be subject to this security policy.   If you are trying to get around this, then you will need to place your MVC WebAPI in your main project.  To combine the two projects, create a new MVC WebAPI project - it comes with service routes as well as regular MVC routes.

---

If you want a truly 'open' WebAPI service, you can follow [this guide to enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/).  In IIS7, you would add this to your web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The projects are already on the same domain though, that is what I am confused about. Is the fact that they are running in separate instances of asp.net development server the issue?

Comment: Yes, when they are on separate port numbers, that counts as another domain.  I'll clarify in my answer.

Comment: Alright I had thought that was the case, I have enabled cors (or so I thought) but I will run through it again. Would it be possible to run them on the same instance or just work on getting cors enabled?

Comment: Implemented cors as stated and didnt it do anything helpful so going to have to go with proxy it looks like

Comment: In terms of 'principles', it's probably better this way as you are separating the client and service and it'll define a boundary between the two which will let you make your service exposable to the public.

Comment: Also keep in mind, the CORS policy would have to have been enabled on IIS, it won't work on a development web server.

Comment: For IIS7

For Microsoft IIS7, merge this into the web.config file at the root of your application or site:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
If you don't have a web.config file already, or don't know what one is, just create a new file called web.config containing the snippet above.


It doesn't seem like I have to modify iis....or do I?

Comment: IIS7 is more integrated with ASP.NET now, so it can be configured based on values in your web.config file. Having that in your web.config is equivalent to configuring iIS7.